# How to remove a vector from a vector 3 list in c# for unity

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, vector

I am struggling to remove vectors from a vector three list. I am trying to spawn a box at a position randomly selected from a list. I then need to remove the item from the list so that two boxes don't spawn in the same place. I have tried RemoveAt and Remove(used vector) but non have worked. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
void Start()
{
Vector3[] Pos = new Vector3[amount_of_pallet];
for (int i =0; i<=amount_of_pallet-1; i++)
{
    Pos[i] = new Vector3(startX, 0.5f, 0f);
    startX = startX + pallet.transform.localScale.x;
    Debug.Log("pos of box = "+Pos[i]);
    Debug.Log("x = "+startX);

}
for (int i=0; i < Pos.Length; i++)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int posi = Random.Range(0, Pos.Length);
    Vector3 val = Pos[posi];
    Instantiate(spawnee, Pos[posi],`Quaternion.identity);` 
    Pos.RemoveAt(posi);
```

Comment: Insteed of Array of vectors (Vector3[]) you should use a List<Vector3> and then to spawn it, you shouldn't put it inside a for loop. Basically when you remove from Array the length of the array doesnt change.

Answer (score 1):

Use list and remove and get func from list

```
void Start()
{ 
    List<Vector3> contList = new List<Vector3>();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount_of_pallet; i++)
    {
        contList.Add(new Vector3(startX, 0.5f, 0f));
        startX = startX + pallet.transform.localScale.x;
    }
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < contList.Count; i++
    {
        var index = Random.Range(0, contList.Count);
        Vector3 position = RemoveAndGet(contList, index);
        Instantiate(spawnee, position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

public T RemoveAndGet<T>(IList<T> list, int index)
{
    lock(list)
    {
        T value = list[index];
        list.RemoveAt(index);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Another solution is shuffle your list and just iterate over it. Something like this:

```
void Start()
{ 
    List<Vector3> contList = new List<Vector3>();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount_of_pallet; i++)
    {
        contList.Add(new Vector3(startX, 0.5f, 0f));
        startX = startX + pallet.transform.localScale.x;
    }
    Shuffle(contList);
    foreach (Vector3 position in contList)
    {
        Instantiate(spawnee, position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    contList.Clear();
}

private System.Random rng = new System.Random();  

public void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> list)  
{  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}
```