# How can I spawn a prefab in Unity in a specific position and then delete that value?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game, a labyrinth, where you have to collect 10 pickups to win the game. Some of those pickups will be always in the same places, but there are others that will spawn in a random  position at the start using a for-loop (previously declared in the code all the possible options). The idea is, when an element has been spawned, the Vector3 containing that position has to be deleted from the List, so it cannot be spawned again in the same place.

I've tried doing it with arrays, but I couldn't delete that value easily, so I decided to try Lists. I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59137577/how-to-remove-a-vector-from-a-vector-3-list-in-c-sharp-for-unity) aiming to use Lists and giving a solution, but when I'm trying it isn't working. The pickups aren't being spawned, but I cannot manage to find the error.

Here's the code:

```
public GameObject pointPrefab;

List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();

public Vector3[] vectorPositions =
{
    new Vector3 (237.05f, 0,- 34.02419f),   // Position 0
    // ... More positions here
    new Vector3 (207.1207f, 0, -74.42f),    // Position 8
};



void Start()
{
    positions.Add(new Vector3(237.05f, 0, -34.02419f));
    // ... More positions here
    positions.Add(new Vector3(207.1207f, 0, -74.42f));


    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        spawnItem();
    }
}

void spawnItem()
{
    int index = selectRandom();
    Vector3 vector = RemoveAndGet(positions, index);
    Instantiate(pointPrefab, vector, Quaternion.identity);
}

int selectRandom()
{
    return Random.Range(0, positions.Count);
}

public T RemoveAndGet<T>(IList<T> list, int index)
{
    lock (list)
    {
        T value = list[index];
        list.RemoveAt(index);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Also, you see there's an array called vectorPositions. I'd like to declare all the Vector3 in that array, and then just use a positions.AddRange(vectorPosition) for assigning all of them to the List (it's easier to read for me). But that's also not working (well, I don't know if it's working or not because pickups aren't spawned)

Hope you can help me, I can't manage to see what's wrong here.

Thanks!

Comment: The best way to check whether your program works and how particularly it works, what goes wrond anв what does not even begin working is to  debug your program with PRINT()'s or DEBUG.LOG()'s

Comment: I'm gonna check right now if I get something clear when debugging, thanks for sharing!

Comment: **HashSet** or **Dictionary** could be more suitable here.

Comment: Debug.Log() should print what I put as arguments in the console, right? Because the spawnItem() isn't getting initialized. I'm gonna check for HashSet and Dictionary too.

Comment: Why don't you rather "shuffle" the list and pick 6 consecutive values? Is there really a need to remove them from the original list? And why `lock`? I don't see any multi threading involved so this seems kind of pointless. Also you know you can just use e.g. `positions = vectorPositions.ToList();` or also `positions = new List<Vector3>(vectorPositions);` ...

Comment: Ok, so first of all, I managed to see what the problem was. It was about how I was assigning the script to the object. Now that's solved and the script is working as expected. I'm gonna search HashSet and Dictionary too. Also, how would I shuffle it?

Comment: `positions = vectorPositions.OrderBy(p => Random.value).ToList();` -> tadaa shuffled list

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for that, I loved this idea. Probably I'll use it.

Comment: Also, how can I make this question to appear as solved?

Comment: You add an answer and after two days you can accept it. Or you let someone else answer and can accept it immediately. Please don't add "solved" to the question titel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing that. E.g. you can simply write

```
positions = vectorPositions.ToList();
```

or also

```
positions = new List<Vector3>(vectorPositions);
```

However, why even create a copy of your array?

You could as well simply make it

```
public List<Vector3> vectorPositions = new List<Vector3>{ ... };
```

If you really need to remove items on runtime.

---

Anyway, you can also way easier generate your 6 random elements using Linq [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) with [`Random.value`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-value.html) as sorting criteria and [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take) in order to take the first 6 consecutive entries from that randomized list

```
using System.Linq;

...

var sixRandomPositions = vectorPositions.OrderBy(p => Random.value).Take(6);
foreach(var position in sixRandomPositions)
{
    Instantiate(pointPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

without changing the original `vectorPositions`.